# What have I to do to use PrimeNG FullCalendar into my Angular project?

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-components

I am very new in Angular and I am finding some difficulties trying to use **PrimeNG FullCalendar** component into my project, this one: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/fullcalendar

In the previous page there is some example code but I am not understandig how exactly I have to use it into my project.

My doubts are:

The official documentation propose this class **FullCalendarDemo**:

```
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

export class FullCalendarDemo implements OnInit {

    events: any[];

    options: any;

    constructor(private eventService: EventService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.eventService.getEvents().then(events => {this.events = events;});

        this.options = {
            plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
            defaultDate: '2017-02-01',
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true
        };
    }

}
```

What exactly is this class. It is not a component because it doesn't have the **@Component** decorator so they are not proposing a component that can be included somewhere in my HTML.

So what is it?

Considering the very basic use case in which I want include the calendar directly into my **app-component** component (I know that probably this is not the best solution and that it should be better put it inside a subcomponent of **app-component** but in a first stage I want take it as simple as possible).

So my idea is:

1) First I put this line into my **app.component.html** page:

```
<p-fullCalendar [events]="events" [options]="options"></p-fullCalendar>
```

Something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <app-header></app-header>
    </div>

    <p-fullCalendar [events]="events" [options]="options"></p-fullCalendar>

</div>
```

Ok if it is correct (I am absolutly not sure of this), then I need to put the code handling this **p-fullCalendar** tag somewhere and here my doubts: where exactly? the previous class is not a component and I don't know if I can put this class code into my **app.component.ts**.

What exactly have I to do? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all it's just minimal representation of what you need to do in your class,
It's only meant to help you understand how to use it and of course you don't need to copy paste the code like that.

Another this make sure you have imported below mentioned module in your module file. as per instructions on this page https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/calendar,

> import {CalendarModule} from 'primeng/calendar';

another thing is make sure you do basic setup for your project that is needed for primeng as per mentioned on this page https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/setup